# Nginx reverse proxy error:14077438:SSL SSL_do_handshake() failed

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

So i am using following settings to create one reverse proxy for site as below.

```
  server {
     listen 80;
     server_name mysite.com;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
     root /home/ubuntu/p3;
   location / {
     proxy_pass  https://mysiter.com/;
     proxy_redirect  https://mysiter.com/ $host;
     proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    }
  }
```

But getting BAD GATE WAY 502 error and below is the log.

```
2016/08/13 09:42:28 [error] 26809#0: *60 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 103.255.5.68, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://105.27.188.213:443/", host: "mysite.com"
2016/08/13 09:42:28 [error] 26809#0: *60 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 103.255.5.68, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://105.27.188.213:443/", host: "mysite.com"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NGINX does currently use TLSv1.3 by default. If your backend enforces TLSv1.3, you will receive a similar SSL_do_handshake() failed error. Tell nginx to use TLSv1.3 by adding the following to your location block: `proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.3`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Seeing the exact same error on Nginx 1.9.0 and it looks like it was caused by the HTTPS endpoint using SNI.

Adding this to the proxy location fixed it:

`proxy_ssl_server_name on;`

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name

Comment: Does not work with Cloudflare? - DNS points to prohibited IP Error 1000

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of oddities with your configuration. Firstly what are you proxying to? Do you have another server block with server name `mysiter.com` listening on port 443 which serves the app? 
If yes, then what you want here is a 301 redirect to your 443 block.
If not, then the proxy will land up in the same location block, forming a loop (because you haven't specified a different port).

The error that you posted is because your upstream doesn't have a certificate to offload the SSL. To solve this, you need to change your `proxy_pass` directive to plain HTTP.

```
proxy_pass  http://mysiter.com/;
```

Or you'll need to provide a certificate for the backend server to use.

Check out the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/) for more info. [This blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-ssl/) might also be of use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - using just `http` instead of a second `https` in the proxy_pass parameter does it for me. I already had the `proxy_ssl_server_name on`

Comment: It works for me proxy_pass http://xxx.de.
You have to come on it for now. Maybe it's HTTP/2 related?