# SSL handshake failing while trying to do a post request from Node (NGINX)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, ssl, next.js

Recently I switched over my NGINX server to HTTPS with `LetsEncrypt` and Certbot (working as intended), and since then every post request in the NextJS/NodeJS API is failing.

At first I was getting ETIMEDOUT error, which resulted in me increasing the proxy timeouts in the NGINX configuration such as:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
send_timeout 300;
```

And after adding those timeouts all I got was 502 Bad Gateway, and the NGINX error.log is as follows:

> SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking
> upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream

or

> upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

For reference, here's the Nodejs call to the API:

```
await fetch("https://[x-redacted-x]/api/getAllPlates", options)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.events.event) {
      syncDatabase(data.events.event);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

And the NGINX configuration:

```
    #nginx config file for Nextjs App
#place in /etc/nginx/sites-available/name_of_config_file
server {
        server_name [x-redacted-x];

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_min_length 256;

        location /_next/static/ {
                alias /var/www/drxl-axis/.next/static/;
                expires 365d;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300;
                proxy_send_timeout 300;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                send_timeout 300;
                auth_basic off;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[x-redacted-x]-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[x-redacted-x]-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = [x-redacted-x]) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name [x-redacted-x];
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I've tried updating the SSL certificates, but that didn't make any difference. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931468/nginx-reverse-proxy-error14077438ssl-ssl-do-handshake-failed

Comment: I already had implemented the suggested solution beforehand, it didn't change anything. Post updated.

Comment: What else does your NGINX server configuration contain?

Comment: Updated the post with full NGINX configuration.